# Size of text in the new Retina MacBook Pros

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I saw there is a new version of MacBook Pro is out which has Retina Display. This means there are more pixel per inch. Does this imply that text is smaller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It depends on your setting.

There is a new option to configure the resolution and rendering in **System Preferences → Color LCD**. While you actually change the resolution and redering, Apple only refers to the **visual impact** of the settings.

So basically changing the setting offers:

1. **Large text**, but much **crispier**.
2. **More space** for visual content (and smaller text), but **not as sharp**.
3. Something in-between (default **retina**).

[image]

(original picture from AndaTech)

Answer (score 10):

As you can see on [the new MacBook Pro page](http://www.apple.com/nl/macbook-pro/features/) (under the Retina-feature item), if you use the binoculars on the text, it doesn't look smaller. It just looks much, much, much sharper!

It's the same as the iPhone 4(S) comparing to the iPhone 3G(S). You don't need better glasses to read the text, because it's not smaller. It's just much sharper and easier to read.

Maybe, I can make my point even better with the [iPad Retina page](http://www.apple.com/nl/ipad/features/). You'll see you can fit as much text on both the Retina screen as the normal screen. It's just sharper!

Before you make a comment, YES, I know it's a screenshot of an iPad and the question is about the new MacBook Pro, but I didn't found any image with this much text on the new MacBook Pro, so hence the iPad Retina screen. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for posting the screenshot. I had some doubts because I saw an IPad 3 in a shop and in Safari it seemed to me that the text was much smaller with respect to the IPad 2.

Comment: @castigli: Unless you made sure to reset the zoom level (pull it all the way out and let it snap back) on each iPad, you could have been seeing zoomed-in text on one of them.

Comment: Actually I found ( http://www.anandtech.com/show/5998/macbook-pro-retina-display-analysis ) that in Mac OSX you have a slider in the settings which you can set and decide if you want more space or bigger text. In any case I have to see it and try it before buying :)

Answer (score 5):

No. Text will be the same size. It will just have two times the resolution in each direction. Just like the difference between the original iPad and the 3rd gen iPad.