# Parallels window problem

Tags: macbook-pro, software, parallels-desktop

I'm using Parallels on my mac. But when I open a software the font are so small, it's very weird. Can anyone help me out!!!

[image: The tool bar of chrome is so small]

The picture above is when I open up my chrome, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this particular problem many times, and a lot of it has to do with how Windows handles DPI scaling.

Since you are using a Retina MBP - which has an extremely high resolution, you'll want Parallels to manage the DPI of your Windows VM. You can do this under your Virtual Machine's configuration, Hardware, Video Options, and select "Best for Retina".

[image]

The next time you reboot, Windows will have its DPI set to 199% (why not 200% I'm not sure).

The only trick to this is when you connect to an external display and you want to show your Parallels VM there. Windows can't change it's DPI without a full logout / login - so if you change displays you'll have to log out of Windows and log back in.

The next problem is that Windows does DPI scaling differently - *some programs do not respect Windows DPI scaling*. It's very bad practices for developers, but some of them always assume a fixed number of points-per-inch, like 96. Windows does its best to fix these issues by bitmap scaling the Window, and translating input, but it won't ever be perfect and it will look like a JPG that's 200% zoomed. It all depends on the program you are using. As unfortunate as it sounds, the best browser on Windows for retina resolution / DPI is Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: I've found out the problem might be the resolution of Retina that windows don't support.  So I've just disabled to let my parallels not to fit my Retina, and it works!

But thanks for your reply!!!! It helps me too.

Comment: @LiJung it sounds like you solved the problem you were having, but I was having the same issue (plus a few others) and fixed it by doing the following: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/89705/46825

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem. I went a different route, and decided to sacrifice the nice high-DPI of the Retina for a scaled solution that makes everything look right.

1. In Parallels VM Config → Hardware → Video → Resolution

   Use: **Scaled**
   Not: Best for Retina, More Space
2. Restart VM
3. Windows Display Settings → Set Resolution: **1280x800** + Apply
4. Windows Display Settings → "Make text and other items larger or smaller"

   Use: Smaller (100%)

<sup>Late-2013 rMBP 13.3″ with Parallels 9.0.23350 and Windows 7</sup>

Comment: Doesnt it look blurry?

Answer (score 2):

I have a new solution for this,set the video properties to "Scaled" and the video memory to 256MB.

[image: Parallels Settings]

One's you do this , go back to your windows--> Control Panel --> Display --> Set it to Smaller(100%).

check the Screen Resolution now it shows 1436*756 on a Mac Book pro 15.6 Retina.

This is done automatically , do not set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

All my coworkers had the same problem. In Parallels 9, you can set for every VM if it should be **scaled**, **best for retina** or **more space**. As DPI scaling under Windows is inherently broken, as application developers have to support this, and many just don't, it's not useful you can configure this at all, which is why more options don't always mean better software (looking at you Parallels). In versions before, Parallels didn't let you choose the wrong things, and didn't have the wrong defaults.

[image: Parallelsmenu -> VM -> Hardware -> Graphics -> resolution -> scaled]

You need to open the VM, go to the Virtual Machine menu item in the Macs menu bar, go to Hardware -> Graphics -> and click on scaled, restart your VM, in the Windows VM, go to Start -> Control Panel -> Display Settings -> click the link "Make text and other items larger or smaller" -> set it to 100%

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem is here... Just forget about all the old advises and read this.

I've MacBook Pro Retina 15"

The problem's started when I've setup Parallel Desktop 9 and installed WIN 8.1, after that I've installed the Parallels Tools .. Than .. on WIN ... the screen resolution is SO high because of the Retina setting on MAC .. and microscopic context menus as will, I cannot use the WIN like this .. 
I tried to play with WIN settings and screen resolution and MAC screen resolution  .. nothing gonna be help

I've forced to uninstall Parallels Tools to disconnect the relation between MAC screen resolution   and WIN screen resolution, BUT I've lost the Audio driver and the Networking between MAC and WIN, Until I found the  solution.

I've just get know how to fix this problem 100% 
It's So easy ..

1- Uninstall Parallels Tools ( On WIN )

2- Update Parallel 9 to the latest update (13-7-2014) or more "important".

3- Shut down the WIN ( Not logout )

4- Exit full screen of Parallel Desktop BUT don't close the Parallel window

5- On MAC .. select the Parallel window than ..: Virtual Machine .. Configure .. select Hardware page .. Video .. remove the check box of " Enable Retina resolution "

6- Install Parallels Tools again .. and That's it .. Enjoy